# Add new edge to graph and find new spanning tree in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Suppose we are given the minimum spanning tree T of a given graph G (with n
vertices and m edges) and a new edge e = (u, v) of weight w that we will add to G.
Give an efficient algorithm to find the minimum spanning tree of the graph G + e.
Your algorithm should run in O(n) time to receive full credit.

(c) from Skiena manual

Start Prim or Kruskal alg from u or v until we reach a fragment of the given spanning tree path?  Seems the new spanning tree won't change a lot from one new edge.

Comment: Since this is a homework problem, can you explain more specifically what you'd like help with?  This is a great problem, but we're not just going to give you the answer.

Answer (score 23):

Determine the path between the endpoints of the new edge in G. If the maximum length edge in that path is greater than that of the new edge, replace it with the new edge. This runs in O(N) time.

Source: [Trail Maintenance IOI 2003](http://ioinformatics.org/locations/ioi03/contest/day1/maintain/data-maintain.pdf)

Comment: Perfect answer for a non-homework question.  But it's a homework question, so -1.

Comment: @j_random_hacker - Some people are curious to know why you downvoted: see [this question on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76694). What should marcog say to make this a better answer to a homework question?

Comment: Wow!  I didn't expect to create so much controversy.  Thanks @ChrisW for the pointer.  I'll try to explain my position on that Meta question (which I think is a great example of a Meta question, BTW).